# If $M=R/(p^k)$ and $N=p^{k-1}M$ then N is contained in every non-zero submodules of M

Tags: commutative-algebra, modules

I have got this problem where I can do but only the tiny last bit of the proof where I got stuck. So here is the problem:

> Let $R$ be a PID, $p\in R$ and irreducible element, $k\ge 1$ and let $M$ be the $R$-module $R/(p^k)$. Let $N=p^{k-1}M$. Show that N is a submodule of M and N is contained in every non-zero submodule of M.

My approach:
M is of the form $\{r+(p^k)|r\in R\}$, so $N=p^{k-1}M=p^{k-1}(r+(p^k))=rp^{k-1}+(p^k)$ where $r\in R$. Let $u=rp^{k-1}+(p^k),v=sp^{k-1}+(p^k)\in N$ where $r,s\in R$. We need to show $u+\rho v\in N$ for $\rho\in R$.

$$u+\rho v=rp^{k-1}+(p^k)+\rho sp^{k-1}+(p^k)$$$$=rp^{k-1}+\rho sp^{k-1}+(p^k)=(r+\rho s)p^{k-1}+(p^k)$$ but since $(r+\rho s)p^{k-1}\in R$, so $(r+\rho s)p^{k-1}+(p^k)\in N$, hence $u+\rho v\in N$.

Now let $\varphi:R\to R/(p^k)$ be natural projection $\varphi(a)=a+(p^k)$. Let $L\le R/(p^k)$ be a non-zero submodule.Then $\varphi^{-1}(N)=(p^{k-1})$ and $L'=\varphi^{-1}(L)$ is a submodule of $R$ that contains $(p^k)$. This is equivalent to $L'$ being an ideal in $R$ that contains $(p^k)$. Then I am stuck.

I know that we need to show $L\supseteq N$ by showing some inclusions in the domain. But how?

Here are some doubts and questions:
1. Is $(p^k)=(p^{k-1})$ ? I think it is since $\frac{1}{p}p^k\in(p^{k-1})$ and $p(p^{k-1})\in (p^k)$. Am I right or wrong?
2. Can $L'$ equal to $(p^k)$? If yes why, if not why not?
3. Do we have to show N is a submodule first before we can show N is contained in every non-zero submodule of M?

Also please feel free to correct my proof on N is a submodule if there are any mistakes.

Thanks very much in advance! I will really appreciate any helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are overcomplicating the problem too much. First recall that an $R$ - submodule of $R/(p^k)$ is just an ideal of this ring. By the correspondence theorem, the ideals of $R/(p^k)$ are in one to one correspondence with the ideals of $R$ that contain $(p)^k$. You should check that the only ideals that contain this are
$$(p)^i, \hspace{5mm} 0 \leq i \leq k$$

with the understanding that $p^0 = (1)$. Now we have the chain of strict inclusions

$$(p)^k \subsetneqq (p)^{k-1}\subsetneqq\ldots  \subsetneqq R$$

and so if we look in the quotient, we have the following strict inclusion of non-zero ideals

$$\Bigg((p)^{k-1}/(p)^k\Bigg) \subseteq \Bigg((p)^{k-2}/(p)^k\Bigg) \subsetneqq \ldots \subsetneqq  R/(p)^k$$

which completes your problem.

Comment: Thanks BenjaLim. You have made it much more clear. But I still couldn't show why the only ideals that contain $(p)^k$ are $(p)^i$ with $0 \leq i \leq k$? Many thanks.

Comment: Sorry now I completely understand it. Thanks very much.